# Android multicastsocket send is dropping packets

Tags: java, android, android-wifi, tcpdump, multicastsocket

I have an app which continuously sends data in multicast socket after joining to a specific IP group. After sending  packets for few hours, all of a sudden it stops sending data. From java socket send is successfull but there is no packet info in tcpdump as well as network packet capture. I have debugged till datagramsocketimpl class, there doesn't seems to have any problem. Suspecting the problem some where after that. Has anyone seen this issue? The data packet just doesn't reach wifi driver. The issue happens randomly no specific procedure.